# vim 8.2 problems with unicode

Tags: vim

Today I updated my vim to 8.2.1883 now I have some problems or let me say display problems.
I'm using vim in the terminal.
In case I will save a file I will get at the line where my cursor is something like this here
[>4;m[>4;2m

Additional the line at the bottom so under my airline looks like this
"my_c_file.c" 3104L, 133202B[>4;m[>4;2m

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: Check if the error is still there when running vim with `vim --noplugins`.  This command will start vim without your plugins.  If the error goes away then you know that the issue is related to a plugin.  Also `vim -u NONE` will skip both your vimrc and plugins.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing this out. I've disabled every plugin and enabled every plugin step by step. I figured out that I had problems with vim v8.2.1883 and the plugins airblade/vim-gitgutter, majutsushi/tagbar or preservim/tagbar. So is their an alternative to the tagbar?

Comment: You might search vimawsome for tagbar alternatives: https://vimawesome.com/?q=tagbar.  Also consider putting in an issue for this with https://github.com/preservim/tagbar.  I'm guessing others are seeing the issue too.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody know how I can fix this?

The answer for [StackExchange -- Vi -- What's t_TE and t_TI added by vim 8?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27400/22621) resolved my issues of odd characters being injected after updating to Vim `8.2.2`

### TLDR

**`~/.vimrc` (snip)**

```
set t_TI=
set t_TE=
```

---

### Vim Documentation

For more information use the following command to jump to Vim's documentation on the subject of what `t_TI` and `t_TE` options do...

```sh
vim -c ':help modifyOtherKeys'
```